# Full list of Targeting Audience options/parameters Facebook Marketing api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

When creating my intended target audiences for the Marketing Ads API I am having to firstly conduct searches via the `/search` API, to then extract the required information to then put into my `Targeting` options of my Adsets.

For Instance I want to see what all the targeting `BEHAVIORS` options are, but I have to very tediously keep applying searches and play around with the data.

My question: Is there a full documented list of all available options and parameters available without having to conduct searches? I cannot see anywhere on the documentation this been available.

Thanks to anyone who can clarify this :)

Cheers.

Comment: Try the `/search` API maybe? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/

Comment: @Bangdel that is what I have been using, thanks for your comment though! Just wondering if there is a list of values rather than querying the api every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done lots more research and it does only seem at this stage that the only way to access this information is by conducting queries via the `search/` API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/